# Memory leak in WPF app on Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-management, memory-leaks, windows-10

There is a big business WPF app with hundreds of thousands of C# lines. I was assigned to it recently. The app uses (up-to-date versions of) third-party components as well (of well-known 3rd party component providers, I don't want to list them).

The memory leak occurs for certain partners only. They start the app in the morning and use it for a few hours before it completely eats memory and gets so slow eventually, that they have to restart it (several times per day). They have Windows 10 machines (but this might not be meaningful). It is not possible to reproduce the leak on my side.

The partners allow me to ship a special version of the app, but Memory Profilers aren't allowed (they want to use the app for production and an attached Profiler would slow it down). So my idea was: **let's ship a special version that logs everything, including clicks of users and handling of "suspicious" GC roots.** As I said, I don't know the code I have to debug, so I identified the potentially leaking GC roots with a memory profiler. (Yes, I made a checklist of possible culprits, such as dependency properties, static lists etc., but no luck so far. As I said, I don't know the source code well enough, but I've access to it and can modify any part of it.)

I'm actually writing a programming question: what should I log besides user behavior and access to static variables? Perhaps I should log the free memory as well after each user action. What's the suitable .NET method for this?

The partners would copy and send the log file before they restart the app.

Comment: I'm shipping my application with the ["Self-profiling" API of dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/2016.2/Profiling_Guidelines__Advanced_Profiling_Using_dotTrace_API.html). The users can set a check box to enable/disable the profiling. Seems to have _performance_ profiling only, not _memory_ profiling.

Comment: I think best bet would be not to log everything, but to collect a memory dump at the point when applicaiton goes slow. Then let client pass that memory dump to you and analyze it.

Comment: @Evk: Is there an API method for that? The partners aren't really competent in IT and they want to do their normal work with the app while "profiling" or logging is in progress. So they can find log txt files but cannot create dumps. They also don't want to call me to come and create a memory dump. (Other problem: some parts of the app aren't so well written, so memory sometimes grows a lot in my own tests, but then after minutes, a big GC occurs and all is OK again. Not on their machines...)

Comment: You can get dump with windows Task Manager (right-click on process, choose Take Dump). Your partners can do that when application becomes slow to the point where they are going to restart it. If that is too complicated for them, you can add a button to your application which they can click to do that.

Comment: @Evk: thanks. Will that be a dump that .NET-specific / *managed memory* profilers understand too? Or only a totally native dump?

Comment: @UweKeim: they seem to have a memory profiler option for that, too:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/10.0/Controlling_Profiling_Process_Through_API.html
So I should perhaps give it a try, thanks!

Comment: ProcDump: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx

Requires you to use command line and access the process id but this is possible from Task manager (Even easier in Windows 10) if you run it with -ma it will collect managed memory information aswell, which can be loaded/debugged in Visual Studio (Enterprise only edition)

Comment: @MaxJ: is it possible to use -ma with Windows Task manager? If not, my best choice is probably shipping ProcDump along a .cmd/bat file that calls it with the necessary switch. Then the user can just run this .cmd file when the app is slowed down.

Comment: @ThomasCalc: Can you reproduce the issue locally?

Comment: @ThomasCalc I don't think so - I initially went the way with using the task manager, but saw it didn't have enough information for me to diagnose the problem, using the ProcDump with -ma lets you fully dive into the managed memory and see what is holding references etc.

Comment: @ThomasCalc I see ChaithJ answered - ANTS Memory profiler was useful (I used the trial) but depending on how much memory is being used, you may not be able to use it. I don't think it can load something using over 4GB

Comment: @MaxJ: Yes, you are correct. It's struggling to profile once the profiling session exceeds 4GB or so... Normally, you don't need to execute something that long to find out if there are any memory leaks. He can test one functionality at a time and avoid growing the memory too much. Just click one functionality 3,4 times and see if there are instances growing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to highlight a few points here for you to select the right track.

1. If there is a memory leak very unlikely it's a windows 10 specific
   issue. You should be able to reproduce the same issue in your
   development PC.
2. Memory leaks (and the causes) are not so easy to track by writing
       logs. You need to know what is exactly hold on to such growing
       instances.
3. I would use a proper memory profiling tool (eg: [ANTS Memory
           profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/walkthrough)) locally (in your dev pc) and try to reproduce the
           issue.

You don't need a very good understanding about the code base to detect the memory leak. Detecting the leak and finding the root cause is 80% of the task here. If you know what objects are growing and what objects are holding onto it, it may not be so difficult to fix it.

Basically what you need to do is.

- Get a good memory profilers (you can use a trial version).
- Find the area/functionality that your customers are using frequently.
- Run the application and get a base memory snapshot.
- Execute the same functionality a few times and take another memory snapshot. Compare the snap shot with the base snapshot and see if there are any growing instances in memory. You should be able to see the objects retention diagram which shows what's hold onto those growing instanes if there is any.
- When you take a memory snapshot, normally memory profilers execute
  GC.Collect and clear all the unnecessary instances from memory. So, you don't need any code changes in order to test the application for memory leaks.
- Test one functionality at a time.

Comment: 1) Good to know. Many partners use this and the leak happens only for a few partners, who seem to have Win10. And they use the app's same functions as the others. But I agree. They experience a leak probably because they use the same function more intensively (and the leak is probably present for others too, they just don't notice).
2) I understand. Actually, logs will help to reproduce what the customers actually do. From their screenrecordings, I tried to reproduce it but no noticeable leak seemed to occur. Nonetheless, I'll update my initial post with an anonymized retention graph.